# Problem while executing ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I am trying to do a simple application using Ajax and servlet. But when i was trying to execute the application, it is not working. 
Please go through the code and let me know what would be the problem?

```
function createRequest()
    {
        alert("hai createRequest()");
        try
        {
            req=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        catch(trymicrosoft)
        {
            try
            {
                req=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(othermicrosoft)
            {
                try
                {
                    req=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(failed)
                {
                    req=null;
                }
            }

        }
        if(req==null)
            alert("req==null");

    }
    function startRequest()
    {
        alert("hai startRequest()");
        createRequest();
        alert("hai created Request()");
        var username=document.getElementById("user").value;
        req.open("get","http://localhost:8080/login/CheckLogin?user="+username,true);
        req.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;
        alert("hai returned from handle state change");
        req.send(null);

    }

    function handleStateChange()
    {
        alert("hai handleStateChange()");
        if(req.readyState==4)
        {
            if(req.status==200)
            {
                var message=req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("valid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=message;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Sorry status failed");
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="Sorry problem in status";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry readyStatus failed");
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="Sorry problem in readyState";
        }
    }
```

The above functions wrote in Javascript and in servlet

```
package com.assignment.login;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CheckLogin extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        System.out.println("Hai i have entered into servlet");
        String userId=request.getParameter("user");
        if(userId!=null && !userId.equals("jeya"))
        {
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.getWriter().write("<valid>U can use this id</valid>");
        }
        else
        {   
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.getWriter().write("<valid>U cannot use this id</valid>");
        }
    }


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        doGet(request,response);
    }
}
```

But in the output the the following alerts are being printed,

```
Hai start request
Hai create request
Hai created request
Hai returned from handle state change
hai handle state change
sorry readyStatus  failed
hai handle state change
sorry readyStatus  failed
hai handle state change
sorry readyStatus  failed
hai handle state change
sorry status  failed
```

My web.xml,

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CheckLogin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.assignment.login.CheckLogin</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CheckLogin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CheckLogin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the servlet i have printed "I have entered into servlet" and it is not getting printed in the server window.. So what would be the problem and please give me suggesstions to resolve it... Thanks in advance...

EDIT:
this is the exception ocuring when i am trying to execute the above application.. But the class CheckLogin is at the right place... But the same code is working in eclipse. So please anyone tell me what the problem may be???
    The requested resource (/login/CheckLogin) is not available.

Comment: Try to fire that from the browser straight and then see whether it hits your servlet or not.

Comment: I am not using any special editors except text editor. So everytime i will fire it directly into the browser.

Comment: Yeah it is not hitting the servlet and thats my question is about.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable suggesstions.

Comment: Next step: jQuery. You don't want to have this boilerplate JS code in production.

Comment: This isn't a question. You need to isolate the problem instead of just posting your code and asking us to debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check whether you have followed the correct naming conventions, because i think there no error in the code.

Comment: Thanks hari.. Yeah i have missed out the naming conventions for WEB-INF. Now its working fine..

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong URL:

```
req.open("get","http://localhost:8080/login/CheckLogin?user="+username,true);
```

i don't know what server you are using, but it will by sufficient to use CheckLogin:

```
req.open("get","CheckLogin?user="+username,true);
```

or
    req.open("get","/login/CheckLogin?user="+username,true);

Probably the server at localhost:8080 isn't reachable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define  **req** variable in the top of the javascript page out side the functions. Like,

```
var req;

function yourFunctions(){

.
.
.
.


   }
```

Try that.

Comment: Yeah i have initialized with the value null at the top and i was forgot to mention..